# Junit Test error : org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to run test code in springboot and it shows the error like below. I cannot understand what NoClassDefFoundError means in this case. I made a PostsRepository class for JPA usage and also wrote @Repository annotation there.

```
`org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/jupiter/api/extension/ScriptEvaluationException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.ScriptExecutionCondition$Evaluator.forName(ScriptExecutionCondition.java:153)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.ScriptExecutionCondition$Evaluator.forName(ScriptExecutionCondition.java:133)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.ScriptExecutionCondition.<init>(ScriptExecutionCondition.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.ScriptExecutionCondition.<init>(ScriptExecutionCondition.java:50)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.ExtensionRegistry.<clinit>(ExtensionRegistry.java:55)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.prepare(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterEngineDescriptor.prepare(JupiterEngineDescriptor.java:28)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$0(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:72)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:83)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:248)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$5(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:226)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:199)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:132)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:414)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ScriptEvaluationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 50 more


UnknownClass > initializationError FAILED
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Class.java:-2
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException at URLClassLoader.java:382
1 test completed, 1 failed
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///C:/BackendWorkspace/java-practice/Spring�ǽ�/CRUD/build/reports/tests/test/index.html
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
BUILD FAILED in 2s
3 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 1 up-to-date

`
```

this is the test code I wrote and I cannot figure out what went wrong. I already set everything in build.gradle and other test codes just ran all good yesterday.

```
 package com.junu.springboot.domain.posts;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class PostsRepositoryTest {
    @Autowired 
    PostsRepository postsRepository;

    @After 
    public void cleanup(){
        postsRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test
    public void selectList(){
        postsRepository.save(Posts.builder()
                                .title(title)
                                .content(content)
                                .author("junu0516@yonsei.ac.kr")
                                .build());
        //when
        List<Posts> postsList = postsRepository.findAll();

        //then
        Posts posts = postsList.get(0);
        assertThat(posts.getTitle()).isEqualTo(title);
        assertThat(posts.getContent()).isEqualTo(content);
    }
}
```

I just guess that the annotaion @Autowired might be the reason because in my Intellij it shows a red line.

Anyone please help me :)

Comment: You seem to be mixing JUnit 4 (`org.junit.*`) with JUnit 5 (`org.junit.jupiter.*`). For instance, the `@RunWith` annotation is for JUnit 4, but the `@SpringBootTest` annotation applies a JUnit 5 extension.

Answer (score 27):

I have got the same issue with `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2`.
It works like a charm by upgrading the version to 5.6.2. (and also the others junit-jupiter-engine, junit-jupiter-api)

Comment: I didn't have a version issue, but was missing the junit-jupiter-api dependency. I just wanted to call that out in case it helped someone.

Comment: Note that 5.7.2 worked for me as well

Comment: Thank you, upgrading to 5.6.2 worked for me!